# How does the swapping of elements in this sorting algorithm make it work?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, indexing

This is a Python sorting algorithm that swaps the current index number with the current element that hold's the smallest value.

My question is if the current becomes element 1 then wouldn't `array[index]=array[1]` which of course is not value 1 but value 3 in the array.

I executed it and the code works and flips the index number that hold value 5 and the one holding value 1.

So if it's working I assume that Python read it as `array[index]=array[2]`
of course I don't understand that because `current=element` and the element is 1.

The code works I got it in a book but I'm trying to understand it more.

```
def selection_sort(array):
    for index in range(0,len(array)-1):
        value=array[index]
        current=index
        #Algorithm go's here
        for element in range(index+1,len(array)):
            if array[element]<array[current]:
                current=element
        array[index]=array[current]
        array[current]=value

        print('\tResolving element[',index,'] to',array)

array=[5,3,1,2,6,4]
print('Selection Sort...\nArray:',array)
selection_sort(array)
print('Array:',array)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what your exact question is, but maybe your misunderstanding is `current=element`. That only sets `current` to the value of `element`, right now. It doesn't link them together forever - `current` may not be equal to `element` in the future, if one of them changes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you talking about is actually [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). The main algorithm is pretty simple:

```
for i from 1 to n-1
{
    Find smallest element in ith to nth entries.
    Exchange this element with ith entry.
}
```

So, the way selection sort algorithm works is by **selecting** the next smallest element and placing it in its correct position. If I illustrate the algorithm little bit more briefly, then it will look like following:

- Step 1 − Set MIN to location 0
- Step 2 − Search the minimum element in the list
- Step 3 − Swap with value at location MIN
- Step 4 − Increment MIN to point to next element
- Step 5 − Repeat until list is sorted

So, the code you provided is working as follows:

```
def selection_sort(array):
    # running through each element of the array
    for index in range(0,len(array)-1):   
        value=array[index]  # storing the current element in a variable
        current=index       # storing the index of the current element

        # search in the sub-array (from index+1 to end of the array) 
        # for the minimum element
        for element in range(index+1,len(array)):
            if array[element]<array[current]:
                current=element

        # swap the minimum value found with the value at location index
        array[index]=array[current]
        array[current]=value
        # at the end of each iteration, minimum value is moved to position index
```

Look into the following animation (taken from Wikipedia):

[image]

**A brief example**: this [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/selection_sort_algorithm.htm) illustrates selection sort very well, you may consider looking into the example.

Comment: if the value in array[1]<array[0]: current=element making array[index]=array[1] am i correct here?

Answer (score 0):

I think your not fully understanding the algorithm. The algorithm uses very ambiguous naming for the variables. Both `element` and `current` refer to indices in the array.

I take it you know that this is a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) algorithm. The way this algorithm works is by 'selecting' the next smallest element and placing it in its corresponding position.

The way they implemented it, is by using the indices to determine which values in the array should be swapped. As mentioned above, the use of `element` as variable name was not great on their side as it is not the element in the array itself but the index of the element.

In the for they simply determine which value in the array should be moved. They do not do any swapping yet. After the for loop is done, the values are swapped.

Hope this helps.